# problem in setting index in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm setting index for the given code as countries name but by using dataframe.set_index(index_name). I'm unable to update the index of the dataframe. I'm currently working on Python 3.7, why this code is not setting up the index?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Nigeria','Bangladesh','China'],
                    'population':[89765,98744,654520],
                    'Birth_Rate':[23.54,34.43,20.3],
                    'Update_Date':['2016-01-18','2016-02-15','2016-02-03']},
                    columns = ['Country','population','Birth_Rate','Update_Date'])                                                        

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India','Sri Lanka','Dubai'],
                    'population':[98343,2453,57432],
                    'Birth_Rate':[33.54,44.44,23.3],
                    'Update_Date':['2016-01-18','2016-02-15','2016-02-03']},
                    columns =['Country','population','Birth_Rate','Update_Date']) 

df3 = df2.append(df1)
df3.set_index('Country')
print(df3)
```

I'm expecting this as output:

```
      Country   population  Birth_Rate Update_Date
0       India       98343       33.54  2016-01-18
1   Sri Lanka        2453       44.44  2016-02-15
2       Dubai       57432       23.30  2016-02-03
0     Nigeria       89765       23.54  2016-01-18
1  Bangladesh       98744       34.43  2016-02-15
2       China      654520       20.30  2016-02-03

but actual output is:
            population  Birth_Rate   Update_Date
Country    
 India       98343       33.54      2016-01-18                               
 Sri Lanka   2453        44.44      2016-02-15
 Dubai       57432       23.30      2016-02-03
 Nigeria     89765       23.54      2016-01-18
 Bangladesh  98744       34.43      2016-02-15
 China       654520      20.30      2016-02-03
```

Comment: Use `df3.set_index('Country', inplace=True)`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa No, it didn't work. The same output I'm getting as there is no change.

Comment: or `df3.reset_index(inplace=True)`?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa thank you sir `df3.set_index('Country',inplace = True)` worked thank you sir for the instant help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the DataFrame index (row labels) using one or more existing columns.

You can use the `DataFrame.set_index(keys, drop=True, append=False, inplace=False, verify_integrity=False)`

Where the parameters define:

> keys : column label or list of column labels / arrays drop : boolean,
>   default True
>
> Delete columns to be used as the new index
>
> append : boolean, default False
>
> Whether to append columns to existing index
>
> inplace : boolean, default False
>
> Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)
>
> verify_integrity : boolean, default False
>
> Check the new index for duplicates. Otherwise defer the check until
>   necessary. Setting to False will improve the performance of this
>   method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Nigeria','Bangladesh','China'],
                    'population':[89765,98744,654520],
                    'Birth_Rate':[23.54,34.43,20.3],
                    'Update_Date':['2016-01-18','2016-02-15','2016-02-03']},
                    columns = ['Country','population','Birth_Rate','Update_Date'])                                                        

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India','Sri Lanka','Dubai'],
                    'population':[98343,2453,57432],
                    'Birth_Rate':[33.54,44.44,23.3],
                    'Update_Date':['2016-01-18','2016-02-15','2016-02-03']},
                    columns =['Country','population','Birth_Rate','Update_Date']) 

df3 = df2.append(df1)
df3.set_index('Country', inplace = True, 
                            append = True, drop = True)
print(df3)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: @user5173426 What IDE is this? Spyder or JupyterLab?

Comment: @HakunaMaData first of all that's a cheesy name! ;-) secondly, I used a online fiddler, https://pyfiddle.io/ cheers!

Comment: Ha! Thanks  and Thanks @user5173426